# Create air intake from submerged water pump...?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm setting up a wet / dry aquarium filter and through the use of a "power head" (which is a completely submerged pump sitting in the sump), I'd like to handle both the water return and the protein skimming (foam generation). So it would be 1 pump for 2 purposes: 75% water return to the main fish tank above and 25% air suction for an air stone that generates foam for the protein skimmer.

The label indicates that the power head has a max pump amount of about 237 GPH (I'm betting it's closer to maybe 200 GPH). The current outlet from the unit is a 1/4" nozzle that I connect to a 5/8" clear tube. My thoughts are to mod the pump or hose to allow just enough air suction to feed the air stone.

What I'm unsure about is whether a mod like this would suck enough air into the tube connecting to an air stone necessary to create foam. Thoughts?

The idea here is to create just enough vacuum necessary to feed the air stone with air while simultaneously pushing water back into the above main tank, all from a single submerged pump (thereby eliminating the need to buy another pump and persist the consolidated sump I've made).

Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: An aquarium forum would be much better suited for this sort of question.  Not only could they help you with the physics, they could provide practical know how about the particular products you are using and the best way to put them together.